# Problem with placing a pressable text in react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native application and I was dealing with Modal and Pressable components, in fact the problem I got is not an error or a bug but I was trying to place a pressable text at the very right down side of the screen but I am struggling with styling a little bit so if anyone can give me a hand in this I would be so grateful.
this the code I wrote for the pop up form component:

```js
import React  from 'react';

import {View, Text, Modal, StyleSheet, Pressable, Alert} from 'react-native';

const PopUpModal = ({visible, onPress})=>{
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={visible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
            }}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
                        <Pressable
                        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                        onPress={onPress}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Cancel</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        width: "100%",
        height : "100%"
    },
    modalView: {
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 35,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 2
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5,
      },
      button: {
        display: "flex",
        borderRadius: 2,
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection:"row-reverse",
        width: 65,
        backgroundColor: "#051316",

      },
      buttonClose: {
       
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        alignItems: "flex-end"
      },
      modalText: {
        marginBottom: 15,
        flexDirection: "row-reverse"
      }
})


export default PopUpModal
```

and this is what it looks like as an output of the above code example
[output pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp7Kq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Pressable inside a View with the style property `flexDirection:"row-reverse"`

```
<View style={{flexDirection:"row-reverse"}}>
    <Pressable
        style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
        onPress={onPress}
        >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Cancel</Text>
    </Pressable>
</View>
```